# Simple XML script is consuming all available memory

Tags: xml, powershell, optimization

I'm trying to create a simple script to add a new proxy for each ip address.
The script gets to id125 before slowing to an absolute crawl. I'm not sure why it's consuming so much memory, can anyone help optimize what i'm doing here?

```
$xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$xml.Load($Path)
$ipAddresses = Get-Content "D:\Downloads\ipaddresses.txt"
$proxy = ($xml.ProxifierProfile.ProxyList.Proxy[0])
$counter = 102
foreach($ipAddress in $ipAddresses){
$newproxy = $proxy.CloneNode($true)  
$newproxy.id = [string](++$counter)
$newproxy.Address = [string]$ipAddress
$proxy.AppendChild($newproxy)
}

$newpath = "c:\temp\newfile.ppx"
$xml.Save($newpath)
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lVDA.jpg)

Comment: Try using a shorter loop, and looking at the resulting XML. I think you have a bug in your logic.

Comment: I suspect you'll find that if you try this with just a short IP address list, you'll see that it's not doing what you expect it to be doing...

Answer (score 1):

Got it working, thanks. Not sure why AppendChild & insertafter don't work similarly...

```
$xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$xml.Load($Path)
$ipAddresses = Get-Content "D:\Downloads\ipaddresses.txt"
$newpath = "c:\temp\newfile.ppx"
$proxy = ($xml.ProxifierProfile.ProxyList.Proxy[-1])
$counter = 101

foreach($ipAddress in $ipAddresses){
$newproxy = $proxy.CloneNode($true) 
$newproxy.id = [string](++$counter)
$newproxy.Address = [string]$ipAddress
$Latestproxy = $xml
$proxy.ParentNode.InsertAfter($newproxy,$proxy)
}


$xml.Save($newpath)
```

Comment: "Not sure why AppendChild & insertafter don't work similarly." They both do exactly what their name suggests: `AppendChild` adds a *child* to the element you call it on. `InsertAfter` adds a new element *after* the given target (the second argument).